# Oracle Error: ORA-12154: TNS: could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Tags: vb.net, oracle, oracle11g, database-connectivity

I am new in oracle. I am using windows 10 64 bit, Oracle XE 11g, visual studio 2010 and vb.net. But Why I am getting 
error:

[image]

related to listener always when I turn off or hibernate my machine
Services are also running.

**This is listner code:**

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = DESKTOP-4R5A2SG)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = (SUIDO)
```

**And This is tnsname.ora code:**

```
SUIDO =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = DESKTOP-4R5A2SG)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = SUIDO)
    )
  )

EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = PLSExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA = 
  (DESCRIPTION = 
    (ADDRESS_LIST = 
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1)) 
    ) 
    (CONNECT_DATA = 
      (SID = CLRExtProc) 
      (PRESENTATION = RO) 
    ) 
  )
```

Can anybody help me what can i do to fix this problem as soon as possible.

Comment: How are you connecting, **remotely or locally**? You do not need listener to connect locally. What client are you using? Are you able to connect locally `/ AS SYSDBA` using `ORACLE_HOME` and `ORACLE_SID` environment variables?

Comment: I am connecting as locally. When i tried to connect  like "SQLPLUS / AS SYSDBA" It ask me for Username and Password. And i put System as username and nepal123 as password which i set while installing oracle. And i also tried to connect like SQLPLUS IBR/IBR@SUIDO, this is my database username and password. but it says "ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect".

Comment: you are actually reporting 3 different problems, based on 3 different approaches to connect. Your original posting reports ora-12154, but now you mention ora-12514.  You also say you get prompted for a password when connecting '/ as sysdba'.  Normally this cannot happen, as that syntax is using os authentication, so I suspect you have TWO-TASK set.  I will address each as a separate proposed answer.

Comment: Additional comment: When you connect with a net service name (sqlplus scott/tiger@fubar' - "fubar" is you net service name) then you are not connecting locally, even if both client and db are on the same hardware. That syntax is directing a network connection.  What you never stated the actual result of that attempt.

Answer (score 0):

First you report ora-12154 - tns could no resolve service connect identifier.
This error means that whatever you specified as the target of your connect was not found in your tnsnames.ora.  Say you specified 'sqlplus scott/tiger@fubar'.  Then the reference to 'fubar' was not found in your tnsnames. End of story.  And that means the request never left the client process and never got anywhere near the listener, so nothing about the listener matters.  I have a more detailed explanation and demonstrations at [https://edstevensdba.wordpress.com/2018/09/19/troubleshooting-ora-12154/](http://edstevensdba.com/oracle-tns/ora-12154tns-03505/)

Answer (score 0):

Second, you report " SQLPLUS IBR/IBR@SUIDO" returns "ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect"."
This is a distinctly different problem with a distinctly different answer.  I see from your tnsnames file the 'suido' resolves to a service_name of 'SUIDO' running on server 'DESKTOP-4R5A2SG', where it expected that there is a listener using port 1521, and that said listner knows about service 'SUIDO'. The error 'ORA-12514' ***definitively*** means that the listener does not know of such a service.  You can prove this out by executing 'lsnrctl status' and observing the services that the listener knows about. I'd say it's near 100 percent certain that the listener does not know of the service because the database is not started.  If the database were started, it should have registered itself with the listener.

There is a more detailed discussion of this error, [here](https://edstevensdba.wordpress.com/2011/03/19/ora-12514//).